# NSItemProvider to photo formats like uiimage or alasset

Tags: ios8

How do I get the image from a NSItemProvider file? When I use -loadItemForTypeIdentifier:kUTTypeImage , I get a NSURL that looks like this

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/103APPLE/IMG_3349.JPG
```

what can I do with it? Thanks!

TAGS: NSItemProvider  NSExtensionItem ios share extensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use

```
[imageItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(id item, NSError *error) {
        if (item)
        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:item];
        }
```

do whatever you want with data

Comment: Not all images shared come through as a URL. I just ran into an issue sharing an image from Evernote. Setting the return type in the completion handler for -loadItemForTypeIdentifier:options:completionHandler: to NSURL returns nil and throws an error. Seems like from this app in particular the return type has to be UIImage.

Comment: If you drag an image from a browser, its type isn't image, it's URL. This code doesn't work most times.

Answer (score 1):

I realized i can actually do this

```
[imageItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(NSData * item, NSError *error) {
if (item)
{
    //do anything with item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, depending on what you want to do with the image:

```
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage
options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

                     NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( image, 1.0f )];

                 }];
```

So this option gives it to you as an image and then you can turn it into NSData if you want to or leave it as an image and display it perhaps, no idea which approach would have the best performance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working is because calling completeRequestReturningItems:completionHandler  at the end dismisses/deallocates the ShareViewController and thus the completion handler would never be reached because it has killed the class.

Try doing something like this instead and you will see:

```
[imageItemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.url" options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Hit here");
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to do it is with load data: 
    [imageItemProvider loadDataRepresentationForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSError *error) {

//Do what you want with the data

}];